# Ckeditor 4 - set anchor inline color

Tags: ckeditor, inline

Is there any solution for CKEditor4 to add inline `style="color:red"` to the anchor tag with color picker?

Currently user creates something like this with color picker

```
<span style="color:red"><a href="#">foo</a></span>
```

and I need

```
<a style="color:red" href="#">foo</a>
```

put in `color:red` to the style input box in anchor dialog is not the way I am looking for.